# Returning records from multiple (4) tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query returning records from multiple tables.

ConfRooms contains a list of rooms
FIDS_Hardware contains information about the hardware in the room
ConfBookings contains a list of booked rooms
ConfRoomOverride contains information on the room status, i.e does the room have an override flag set

Return all the records from "ConfRooms AS c" where c.HotelID = 'EXBHX'.

Return all the records from "FIDS_Hardware AS h" where r.HotelID = 'EXBHX' AND c.ConfRoomID = h.deviceID.

Return all the record from "ConfBookings AS b" where HotelID = 'EXBHX' AND c.ConfRoomName = b.RoomName.

Return all the record from "ConfRoomOverride AS o" where HotelID = 'EXBHX' AND c.ConfRoomNID = b.RoomID

At the moment my query is not returning all the records from "ConfRooms" but returns only the room that have a booked status in ConfBookings.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

```
SELECT 
h.messageCount,
h.deviceID, 
c.ConfRoomName, 
r.DisplayMainBoard, 
r.RecordID, 
r.RoomID, 
r.RoomName,
r.RoomBooked,
r.RoomFromDate,
r.RoomToDate,
r.FullBoardRoom, 
COUNT(r.RecordID) AS RC,
r.Override,
r.HotelID,
o.Override AS ConfOverride
FROM
ConfRooms AS c
Left Join FIDS_Hardware AS h ON (c.ConfRoomID = h.deviceID)
Left Join ConfBookings AS r ON (c.ConfRoomName = r.RoomName)
Left Join ConfRoomOverride AS o ON (c.ConfRoomID = o.RoomID)
WHERE c.HotelID = 'EXBHX' 
AND r.HotelID = 'EXBHX'
AND h.hotelID = 'EXBHX'
GROUP BY c.ConfRoomID
ORDER BY h.messageCount DESC,
ConfOverride DESC, 
r.RoomBooked DESC,
c.ConfOrder ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this :

```
SELECT 
h.messageCount,
h.deviceID, 
c.ConfRoomName, 
r.DisplayMainBoard, 
r.RecordID, 
r.RoomID, 
r.RoomName,
r.RoomBooked,
r.RoomFromDate,
r.RoomToDate,
r.FullBoardRoom, 
COUNT(r.RecordID) AS RC,
r.Override,
r.HotelID,
o.Override AS ConfOverride
FROM
ConfRooms AS c
Left Join FIDS_Hardware AS h ON (c.ConfRoomID = h.deviceID AND h.hotelID = 'EXBHX')
Left Join ConfBookings AS r ON (c.ConfRoomName = r.RoomName AND r.HotelID = 'EXBHX')
Left Join ConfRoomOverride AS o ON (c.ConfRoomID = o.RoomID)
WHERE c.HotelID = 'EXBHX' 
GROUP BY c.ConfRoomID
ORDER BY h.messageCount DESC,
ConfOverride DESC, 
r.RoomBooked DESC,
c.ConfOrder ASC
```

The problem is that your WHERE clause removes the benefits of your multiple left joins.

When you left join FIDS_Hardware AS h, it means that h values can be null but when you are executing "h.hotelID = 'EXBHX'" in your where clause you only select rows where h values are not null (a row has matched).

So what you need to do is to move these conditions right inside the ON clause of the left join as above.

Comment: Perfect, I have been playing around for hours but with another set of eyes looking at it helped.Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Added some explanation, glad to have helped you